# select only albums with photos in them

Tags: php, mysql

`albums` table is `aid | name | description | privacy | defaultpic | date | uid` and `photos` table is `id | date | uid | file | description | size | height | width | mime | aid | deleted`

```
$AlbumListSQL = mysql_query("SELECT aid, defaultpic FROM albums WHERE $privacycheckSQL AND uid='$userid' LIMIT $start , $limit");
```

selects albums no matter if they have photos in them or not. `$privacycheckSQL` can be `privacy='0'` or `(privacy = '0' OR privacy ='1' OR privacy ='2')` or `(privacy = '0' OR privacy ='1' OR privacy ='2')`

`SELECT COUNT(id) FROM photos WHERE deleted=0 and uid='$userid' AND aid='$aid'` returns the count of the photos for a album. Can i write this in to one query somehow that will return albums with over zero photos in them? I was thinking some type of join or nested query. I'm not sure.

I'm using 5.1.54 if that means anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a JOIN , which will only bring albums which have matching records in photos table, Group By will return only one record per album.

```
SELECT albums.aid, albums.defaultpic 
FROM albums JOIN photos on (albums.aid = photos.aid and photos.deleted = 0)
WHERE $privacycheckSQL AND albums.uid='$userid' 
GROUP BY aid
LIMIT $start , $limit
```

Comment: also be sure to escape $privacycheckSQL with mysql_real_escape_string to avoid SQL Injection if you dont' control $userid.

Comment: I'm getting "Column 'aid' in field list is ambiguous"

Comment: @Keverw I updated the query to `albums.aid`. MySQL just wants to know exactly which aid you are talking about.